# Почему функция не принимает новый аргумент?

Tags: php, массивы, php7

Есть функция

```
function checkSunday($result)
{
$a = 0;
foreach ($result as $key => $res)
{
    if (strftime("%A", $res) === 'Sunday')
    {
        $resultNew = shift($result, $key);
        $a++;
        break;
    }
}
if ($a === 0) {insert($resultNew); return true;}
else {reCall($resultNew); return false;}
}
```

Она вызывает функцию записи, если в массиве не найдено дат с воскресеньем, в обратном случае вызывает функцию, которая вызывает снова ее с переданным параметром:

```
function reCall($result)
{
  checkSunday($result);
}
```

Проблема в том что новый массив, который обработала функция в первый раз не передается, а вместо него отправляется старый, тот что был до первой обработки.

```
function shift($array, $elem)
{
for ($i = $elem; $i < sizeof($array)-$elem-1; $i++)
{
    $array[$i] = $array[$i] + 1 * 24 * 3600;
}
return $array;
}
```

В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Если `$result` пустой в  `checkSunday`, то `$resultNew` никогда не случится. Если условие в цикле никогда не выполнится, `$resultNew` никогда не случится. Вы ещё спрашиваете почему не работает?

Comment: И какой смысл в reCall? Можно же сразу checkSunday вызвать.